# Java applet program to calculate the KwH Used, Electric Bill, System Charges and Total Bill in a certain place. (Electric billing system)

Tags: java, applet, awt

Can someone help me to determine what is the problem here? I'm trying to compile a java applet program. But the problem is whenever I try to click the "compute" or "clear" button, nothing seems to work. I'm trying to change my conditions to try catch form but I don't know how can I implement it. This is the system's condition:

https://pasteboard.co/JQ7sEaD.png

And here is my own code:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ElectricReading extends Applet implements ActionListener, ItemListener
{
    Label txt = new Label ("Area:");
    CheckboxGroup area = new CheckboxGroup();
    Checkbox df = new Checkbox("Default",true,area);
    Checkbox mm = new Checkbox("Metro Manila Area",false,area);
    Checkbox pa = new Checkbox("Provincial Area",false,area);
    
    Label an = new Label("Account Number:");
    Label cn = new Label("Customer Name:");
    Label pr = new Label("Previous Reading:");
    Label cr = new Label("Current Reading:");
    Label ku = new Label("KwH Used:");
    Label at = new Label("Account Type:");
    Choice ch = new Choice();
    Label eb = new Label("Electric Bill:");
    Label sc = new Label("System Charges:");
    Label tb = new Label("Total Bill:");
    
    TextField anTF = new TextField(" ", 20);
    TextField cnTF = new TextField(" ", 20);
    TextField prTF = new TextField(" ", 20);
    TextField crTF = new TextField(" ", 20);
    TextField kuTF = new TextField(" ", 25);
    TextField ebTF = new TextField(" ", 20);
    TextField scTF = new TextField(" ", 20);
    TextField tbTF = new TextField(" ", 20);

    Button comp = new Button("Compute");
    Button clr = new Button("Clear");

    
    public void init()
    {
        resize(350,500);
        
        add(txt);
        add(df); df.addItemListener(this);
        add(mm); mm.addItemListener(this);
        add(pa); pa.addItemListener(this);
        
        add(an); add(anTF);
        add(cn); add(cnTF);
        add(pr); add(prTF);
        add(cr); add(crTF);
        add(ku); add(kuTF); kuTF.setEditable(false);
        add(at); add(ch);
        ch.add(" ");
        ch.add("Residential");
        ch.add("Commercial");
        ch.add("Industrial");    
        add(eb); add(ebTF); ebTF.setEditable(false);
        add(sc); add(scTF); scTF.setEditable(false);
        add(tb); add(tbTF); tbTF.setEditable(false);
        
        add(comp); comp.addActionListener(this);
        add(clr); clr.addActionListener(this);
        
    }
    
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
    {
        float prevReading = Float.parseFloat(prTF.getText());
        float currReading = Float.parseFloat(crTF.getText());
        int r = 15, c = 30, i = 45;
        Choice ch = (Choice) e.getItemSelectable();
        
        if(currReading > prevReading)
        {
            float ku = currReading - prevReading;
            kuTF.setText(String.valueOf(ku));
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect Reading", "Message", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
        
        if(mm.getState() && ch.getSelectedItem().equals("Residential"))
        {
            float eb = (ku * r);
            ebTF.setText(String.valueOf(eb));
            float sc = (eb * 0.03);
            scTF.setText(String.valueOf(sc));
        }
        else if(mm.getState() && ch.getSelectedItem().equals("Commercial"))
        {
            float eb = (ku * c);
            ebTF.setText(String.valueOf(eb));
            float sc = (eb * 0.06);
            scTF.setText(String.valueOf(sc));
        }
        else if(mm.getState() && ch.getSelectedItem().equals("Industrial"))
        {
            float eb = (ku * i);
            ebTF.setText(String.valueOf(eb));
            float sc = (eb * 0.09);
            scTF.setText(String.valueOf(sc));
        }
        if(pa.getState() && ch.getSelectedItem().equals("Residential"))
        {
            float eb = (ku * r);
            ebTF.setText(String.valueOf(eb));
            float sc = (eb * 0.02);
            scTF.setText(String.valueOf(sc));
        }
        else if(pa.getState() && ch.getSelectedItem().equals("Commercial"))
        {
            float eb = (ku * c);
            ebTF.setText(String.valueOf(eb));
            float sc = (eb * 0.04);
            scTF.setText(String.valueOf(sc));
        }
        else if(pa.getState() && ch.getSelectedItem().equals("Industrial"))
        {
            float eb = (ku * i);
            ebTF.setText(String.valueOf(eb));
            float sc = (eb * 0.06);
            scTF.setText(String.valueOf(sc));
        }
            
    }

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    try
    {
    if(e.getSource()==comp)
        {
        Choice ch = (Choice) e.getItemSelectable();
            if(ch.getSelectedItem().equals(""))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Selection Was Made","Error Message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
            else
            {
                float totalBill = eb + sc;
                tbTF.setText(String.valueOf(totalBill));
            }
        }
    else if(e.getSource()==clr)
    {
        anTF.setText("");
        cnTF.setText("");
        prTF.setText("");
        crTF.setText("");
        kuTF.setText("");
        ebTF.setText("");
        scTF.setText("");
        tbTF.setText("");
        df.setState(true);
        ch.select(0);
    }
    }
    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e1) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Input a correct positive integer value", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
}
}
```

Comment: could you be more specific than: "nothing seems to work" ? Have you added some logging? Did you debug your code?

Comment: Yes. It does run at some point. But whenever I try to put values and press the compute button, it doesn't seem to calculate the given values. In fact, no values are shown at all.

Comment: I cannot even compile it. For example on the line 88 `float eb = (ku * r);` the compiler tells me "error: bad operand types for binary operator '*'" and on the line 90 `float sc = (eb * 0.03);` the compiler tells me "error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to float"

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 3) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT components in favor of Swing.